# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'dict'?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import json

def load_data(filepath):
    with open(filepath, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8') as row_data:
        return json.load(row_data)

def get_biggest_bar(data):
    return max(data, lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])

def get_smallest_bar(data):
    return min(data, lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])

json_content = load_data(input('Введите путь к файлу: '))
get_biggest_bar(json_content)
get_smallest_bar(json_content)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Adderall/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 21, in <module>
>     get_biggest_bar(json_content)
>   File "C:/Users/Adderall/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 11, in get_biggest_bar
>     return max(data, lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'dict'
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18296755/4928642

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return max(data, lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])
> ```

```
return max(data, key=lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])
```

Comment: Ваши ответы регулярно попадают в очередь сообщений низкого качества, видимо из-за отсутствия пояснений)

Comment: @andreymal, я только добавил `key=`. И ещё написал комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: Видимо, стоит рассказать, что это за key такой и что он изменил ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Ссылки в комментах устраивают не всех