# Помогите найти ошибку TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import json
from math import sqrt


def load_data(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as row_data:
        return json.load(row_data)


def get_biggest_bar(data):
    return max(data, key=lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])


def get_smallest_bar(data):
    return min(data, key=lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])


def get_closest_bar(data, longitude, latitude):
    calc_distance = lambda x: sqrt((float(x['Longitude_WGS84']) - longitude)**2
                               + (float(x['Latitude_WGS84']) - latitude)**2)
    return min(data, key=calc_distance)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = load_data(input('Введите путь к файлу: '))
    get_biggest_bar(filename)
    get_smallest_bar(filename)
    lat = float(input('Latitude: '))
    lon = float(input('Longitude: '))
    get_closest_bar(filename, lat, lon)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Adderall/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 28, in <module>
        get_biggest_bar(filename)
      File "C:/Users/Adderall/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 12, in get_biggest_bar
        return max(data, key=lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])
      File "C:/Users/Adderall/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 12, in <lambda>
        return max(data, key=lambda x: x['SeatsCount'])
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: [Снова этот код...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728597/178988) Что в data находится?

Comment: большой json файл

Comment: Нужно также приводить **минимальный воспроизводимый пример** и результат который хотите достигнуть, а так по ошибке могу судить, что `data` содержит словарь, а не список. Как получить ошибку: `max({'a': 1}, key=lambda x: x['a'])`. Как сделать правильно: `max([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 4}], key=lambda x: x['a'])`